# How to implement nested submenus in the administrative sidebar?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, custom-component, view

I'm using JHtmlSidebar::addEntry() to build a menu in the sidebar. However, I need a better way to organize the menu items in there. I don't see a way to easily create a nested menu structure. I'm guessing that there isn't. If not, is there a way to add css selectors to the links that are created by JHtmlSidebar? What is the best way to organize items?